# using priority with broadcast receivers

Tags: android

Can we use priority

```
android:priority
```

with

```
Context.sendBroadcast
```

also or it will give results different from

```
Context.sendOrderedBroadcast
```

thanks

Comment: While i think I've answered this, i wouldn't mind having @Commonsware's opinion on this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot use `android: priority` with `sendBroadcast`. As the docs say:

```
android: priority
```

*It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The order **applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages**.)
**Use this attribute only if you really need to impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want to force Android to prefer one activity over others**.*

**Now looking at what we know about `sendBroadcast` which is a `Normal broadcast`**:

*Normal broadcasts (sent with `Context.sendBroadcast`) are **completely asynchronous (not orderly)**. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined order, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.*

**For `sendOrderedBroadcast`, which is an `Ordered broadcast`:**

*Ordered broadcasts (sent with `Context.sendOrderedBroadcast`) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be **controlled with the `android:priority` attribute** of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.*

Comment: When using priority with sendBroadcast ,the order in which the receivers are listed in the manifest file they are called .changing the order changes the order in which broadcast receivers are called.is it just by chance or it really follows such logic.

Comment: Yes it does follow such logic.

Comment: accepting the answer would be great if you found it helpful :)

Comment: I have tested with the `android:priority` in receiver tag in manifest it is working even I send broadcast using `sendBroadcast` method.